# how to connect to mysql with SSL in Netbeans 8.0

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, netbeans

I am trying to connect to a remote mysql server that requires a connection with SSL. I have been provided with a .key, .cert and CA certificate files. I have imported the .cert file into keytools with:

```
 keytool -import -alias mysqlclientcertificate -file mycert.crt
```

In NetBeans, when I create a new connection using Services->Databases->Drivers->MySQL(Connector/J driver) I am prompted with a panel where I specify the host, the user and password and finally I add connection parameters like:

```
useSSL = true
requireSSL = true
```

I think I am missing some step here, but cannot figure out what exactly, and I couldn't find on Google any pointer to solve this issue...

Is there anyone that succeeded in establishing such a connection within NetBeans 8.0?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbname"
                        + "?verifyServerCertificate=false" + "&useSSL=true"
                        + "&requireSSL=true";
        String user = "username";
        String password = "userpass";
        Class dbDriver = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have a SQLException:
java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '93-46-154-31.ip108.fastwebnet.it' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Comment: are you sure the server accepts ssl connections ?? can you ping the server ? are the ports open and ready to except connections ?

Comment: it should accept connections, as I have been told by the buddy that manages the server... maybe it's on my side that something is missing, like adding some certificates to my Java trust store? I have only added the .cert file...